# bind() returns error code 10038 using winsock.h

Tags: c, sockets, bind, winsock

I am trying to implement a client-server architecture using sockets in Windows with `winsock.h`. When I call `bind()` function I get the error code 10038 and I don`t know why.

Here it is my code. This is only the server, created inside a thread where I initialice the socket and jump into an infinite loop to read data from client usng `recvfrom` function.

```
typedef struct
{
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in dir_client;
    int long_dir_client;
    struct sockaddr_in dir_server;
    uint32_t receive_data;
}server_t;


void RX_thread_Client(void)
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    server_t server;
    int iResult;
    int BytesReceived;

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("[RxThreadClient] WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return;
    }

    memset((char*)& server.dir_server, 0, sizeof(server.dir_server));
    server.dir_server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.dir_server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.128.169.46");
    server.dir_server.sin_port = htons(6500);
    server.long_dir_client = sizeof(server.dir_client);

    // Create a new socket to make a client connection.
    // AF_INET = 2, The Internet Protocol version 4 (IPv4) address family, TCP protocol
    if ( server.sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("[RxThreadClient] Client: socket() failed! Error code: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        // Do the clean up
        WSACleanup();
        // Exit with error
        return;
    }
    else
        printf("[RxThreadClient] Client: socket() is OK!\n");

    if ( bind(server.sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&server.dir_server, sizeof(server.dir_server)) < 0)  // ERROR IS HERE!!!
    {
        printf("[RxThreadClient] bind() failed! Error code: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return;
    }
    else
        printf("[RxThreadClient] Client: bind() is OK!\n");

    while (1)
    {
        BytesReceived = recvfrom (server.sockfd, (char*)&server.receive_data,
                                  sizeof(server.receive_data), 0,
                                  (struct sockaddr*) & server.dir_client,
                                  &server.long_dir_client);
        if (BytesReceived == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("[RxThreadClient] Client: send() error %ld.\n", WSAGetLastError());
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("[RxThreadClient] Client: send() is OK - bytes received: %ld\n", BytesReceived);
            printf("[RxThreadClient] Word received: %d\n", server.receive_data);
        }

        Sleep(1000);
    }
 }
```

Thank you very much

Comment: The error `10038` is `WSAENOTSOCK`, which means you're trying to perform an operation on something which isn't a socket. Where exactly do you get this error?

Comment: Ah I see it... The expression `server.sockfd = socket(...) == SOCKET_ERROR` is really `server.sockfd = (socket(...) == SOCKET_ERROR)`, so you're assigning a boolean result to `server.sockfd`.

Comment: That is it! I put `if ( (server.sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == INVALID_SOCKET)` and now the `bind` operation works. Thank you very much!

Comment: On a side note, Winsock does not use `int` to represent sockets, it uses the `SOCKET` handle type (which is a `UINT_PTR`, ie `unsigned int` for 32bit, `unsigned __int64` for 64bit). This is different than non-Windows platforms, which do represent sockets as `int` descriptors. This is why you can't use Winsock sockets in descriptor-based functions, like `read()`/`write()`/`close()`, so Winsock exposes its own extensions to operate on `SOCKET`s. So, IOW, since your code is clearly targeting Winsock specifically and not cross-platform, you should change `int sockfd;` to `SOCKET sockfd;` instead.